# Desactivar textfields

Tags: java-swing

Estoy realizando una app de escritorio para gestionar inscriptos de distintas edades a diversos cursos. Estoy trabado, y por eso les escribo para que me ayuden a solucionar, ya que necesito que a partir del cálculo de la edad del inscripto (menor de 18 años) se desactiven ciertos txt que corresponden a datos para adultos: antecedentes laborales y cursos de capacitación. Hice distintas pruebas, y algunas me arrojan error de nullFormatException y otras me desactivan los txt independientemente de la edad del inscripto.
En sql, por ejemplo el campo fechaNacimiento es date null, y en la clase inscripto en netbeans la declaré como String. Al ejecutar el abm todo funciona bien, solo que estoy validando campos y me falta desactivar estos txts apartir de la edad.
Les muestro el código que generé. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
    private void txtEdadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    DateTimeFormatter date = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
    LocalDate fecNac = LocalDate.parse(txtFechaNacimiento.getText(), date);
    LocalDate fecHoy = LocalDate.now();

    Period periodo = Period.between(fecNac, fecHoy);

    String edad = (" " + periodo.getYears());
```

### txtEdad.setText((edad));//Esto funciona bien, me calcula la edad.

//A partir de aquí empecé con las diversas pruebas. Las que dicen Anda? me desactivan los txts independientemente de la edad.

//

```
    String fecha = txtFechaNacimiento.getText();// No anda.
//        int f = Integer.parseInt(fecha);// No anda.
//        int e = Integer.parseInt(edad);//No anda.
//        int e = Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText());//No anda.
//        int e = Integer.parseInt("18");//Anda?
//        int f = Integer.parseInt(txtFechaNacimiento.getText());//No anda.

//        int e = 18;
          int e = Integer.valueOf("18");//Anda?
//        int e = Integer.valueOf(edad);//No anda.



//        int e = Integer.parseInt(("18"));//Anda?
          if (e<=18) {   
//        if(f<2001/01/01){

            txtTitCurso.setEnabled(false);
            txtInstitucionCC.setEnabled(false);
            txtAnio.setEnabled(false);
            txtDuracionEnHs.setEnabled(false);
            btnCCCompSI.setEnabled(false);
            btnCCCompNO.setEnabled(false);
            btnCCCurSI.setEnabled(false);
            btnCCCurNO.setEnabled(false);
            txtHabilidades.setEnabled(false);
            txtEmpresa.setEnabled(false);
            txtPuesto.setEnabled(false);
            txtRubro.setEnabled(false);
            txtDomicilioAL.setEnabled(false);
            txtTelefonoAL.setEnabled(false);
            txtOtrosAL.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo haria luego de calcular la edad,  con un `If`  habilitar o deshabilitar lo que quieras dependiendo de la edad

```
if(edad >=18){
  // habilitar todo
} else if(edad<18){
  // deshabilitar y/o ocultar los campos que desees
}
```

Comment: Gracias x tu comentario. El problema q estoy teniendo es q me deshabilita todo aún la edad sea mayor a 18; según esos métodos con los q probé, los habilita o no. No alcanzo a darme cuenta con el tema del cast xq la fecha de nacimiento es localDate y la edad la cálculo contra la fecha del sistema, y después la guardo en un string y de ahí la paso a int para la condición del if. Incluso probé con la fecha de nacimiento en vez de la edad xq la edad  no se actualiza, pero no me logré hacerlo deshabilitar.

Comment: de nada, veamos en lo que pusiste esta solo la verificacion de sí es menor de edad, no sé si al tuyo le agregaste el If para mayor de 18 años; de todas fornas te recomiendo que confirmes si te esta calculando bien la edad , puedes poner un label que muestre la edad calculada a modo de prueba y luego lo quitas porque quiza se esta manteniendo el valor 18 solamente ya que lo inicializaste en ese valor

Comment: Mí duda está en las líneas de código q dicen //Anda?, xq me desactiva los txt, pero es igual si es mayor o no a 18. Los demás ejemplos me dan error de nullFormatException, ahí está la cuestión dsd mí Punto de vista